# How can i fill gameobject to closed area with list and arrays?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Here is my code

```
if ((transform.position.x == 0 || transform.position.x == 100)
            || (transform.position.z == 0 || transform.position.z == 100))
        {
            float posX = transform.position.x;
            float posZ = transform.position.z;
            for (float x = posX; x >= 0; x -= 10)
            {
                for (float z = posZ; z >= 0; z -= 10)
                {
                    Vector3 foundEmptyPosition = new Vector3(x * 10, 10, z * 10);
                    if (!IsExists(foundEmptyPosition))
                    {
                        PutACube(foundEmptyPosition);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Which algorithm do i use for filling?
[Here is the example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rurISTkZqSE)

Answer (score 0):

What you do is asking for literally whole game logic. It's impossible.

1. In common, you have to have 2-dimensional array which will represent state of your game field.
2. Then you have to group non-painted indexes and simultaneously determine are they surrounded or not. This looks easy - while gathering information about group check nearby cube. To determine should a group be auto-painted each cube has to have either painted or non-painted cube. If you do find it touches the border or whatever else, you can understand whole group is not the one you are looking for.
3. Paint groups that marked as suitable for the painting

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first thought

it has not been tested and may contain some bugs

**definitions**

"cell" means the ground that you put the cube on

"empty cell" means there is no cube on it

"occupied cell" means there is a cube on in

"captured cell" means the "empty cell" is surrounded by the "occupied cells" and should be filled

when you adding a new cube on a cell (empty cell -> occupied cell)

you only need to check the neighbor cells (4-way) of this occupied cell
that means when adding new cube on cell (x, z) = (2, 2)

start to check the neighbor cells (x, z) => (1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)

i call these neighbor cells as GROUP A

**recursive check the neighbor cells** of the GROUP A, if all check says the neighbor cells only has "occupied cell"

then all of the cells should be "captured"

Code Example

```
void FillCapturedCellAfterAddingCubeOnCell(Cell cell)
{
    // the cell's hash code should be '(x,z)' or something
    HashSet<Cell> checkedCells = new HashSet<Cell>();
    checkedCells.Add(cell);
    HashSet<Cell> connectedCells = new HashSet<Cell>();
    List<Cell> neighbors = cell.GetNeighbors();
    foreach (var neighborCell in neighbors)
    {
        if (checkedCells.Contains(neighborCell))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (neighborCell.IsFilled)
        {
            continue;
        }

        bool captured = RCheckCellCaptured(neighbourCell, ref checkedCells, ref connectedCells);
        if (captured)
        {
            // the connected cells is empty and should be captured
            // fill all connected cells
            foreach (var capturedCell in connectedCells)
            {
                
            }
        }

        checkedCells.Clear();
        connectedCells.Clear();
    }
}

bool RCheckCellCaptured(Cell cell, ref HashSet<Cell> checkedCells, ref HashSet<Cell> connectedCells)
{
    checkedCells.Add(cell);
    if (!cell.IsFilled)
    {
        connectedCells.Add(cell);
    }
    List<Cell> neighbors = cell.GetNeighbors();
    foreach (var neighborCell in neighbors)
    {
        if (checkedCells.Contains(neighborCell))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // your game logic: if the cell is in some state,
        // then that means all connected neighbors should not be captured
        if (neighborCell.IsWall || neighborCell.EnemyOnIt)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!neighborCell.IsFilled)
        {
            bool captured = RCheckCellCaptured(neighborCell, ref checkedCells, ref connectedCells);
            if (!captured)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```